# blur event text field jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the blur event event on a text field

```
$(document).on('blur', '#inputEmail', function(event){

    // logic here

});
```

When I put some text in the field click and drag on a draggable element using [jQuery draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/), the event does not execute when I drop the element.

How can I fix this? It's kind of annoying.

Thanks in advance

Comment: call the blur manually on button click?

Comment: The blur event is triggered when the element loses focus, so to confirm, what you want is the input to blur when you click the button ?

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '#button', function(event){

    $('#inputEmail').blur();

});` try something like this

Comment: I want the input to blur when I click on anything (not just the button) and also when I click and drag on something

Comment: Have you bound any event to the button earlier?

Comment: Sorry people but the question is more when I drag on something as opposed to when I click on a button (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the `blur` event, it might be a good idea to use the tradition `event delegation` approach. Listen for the blur event on your input with an id of `inputEmail`.

```
$("#inputEmail").on("blur", function(event) {
    alert('hi');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1qyhjshu/1

Edit: It looks like your first example worked for me as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/vbdxwt9b/

Comment: It's more when  I click and drag on an element that it does not work (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make hit on the button only after executing the code in blur event.You may hide the button and show he button after executing the blur function.

```
      $("#inputEmail").blur( function(event) {
      //code here
      $("#btn").show();

      });
```

Comment: It's more when I drop a draggable element into place that it doesn't work. I changed the question